# Special characters as function names in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
function _(x){
 return document.getElementById(x);
}
```

I would like to do the same think for `getElementByClassName`, but aside from "$" are there any other special characters I can use? I was thinking about may å or some accented character, but I don't know if it will work or not.

Is there any downside to doing something like this?

```
function å(x){
  return document.getElementByClassName(x);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1661197/613130 function names should be the same.

Comment: @xanatos can you post that as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate IMO. *"Is there any downside to doing something like this?"* Is a bit subjective I think. Depending on what language you use on your computer, some names might be difficult to type.

Comment: Just flagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the name of a function/variable must start with _, $ or a letter (even accented/with other diacritics)

Here they spoke at length of it: [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661197/613130)

Comment: Thanks, flagged it as duplicate. I'm not a ninja searcher :D